# Bazel kotlin build target cannot resolve classes from intellij SDK

Tags: intellij-idea, bazel-java

I am developing an intellij plugin, and I use bazel to build my project.

When I run the build, I see a lot of errors related to class in intellij SDK. Such as:

```
error: unresolved reference: VirtualFile
```

which refers to

```
com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFile
```

I am not sure how to resolve this.

When I compare it to a gradle setup, it looks like gradle has a proprietary logic for this, and all I see is a gradle dependency that I cannot find in any maven repository. (com.jetbrains:ideaIC:241-EAP-SNAPSHOT)

At some point I reached [Intellij Snapshot repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/snapshots) and I tried to install different maven dependencies such as `com.jetbrains.intellij.idea:ideaIC:241-EAP-SNAPSHOT` which seems close. But this does not resolve the problem, and does not seem to be the right approach.

My bazel target currently looks like

```
kt_jvm_library(
    name = "kotlin_sources",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/kotlin/**/*.kt"]),
    deps = [
        "@maven//:nl_basjes_maven_enforcer_codeowners_codeowners_enforcer_rules",
        "@maven//:com_google_code_gson_gson",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Maybe you could ask this in https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/issues. I guess not a lot of people use Bazel for developing IntelliJ plugin and IntelliJ Bazel developer may have some idea about your issue.

Comment: @LJreplica thank you for the suggestion - but that plugin is not aligned with what I am trying to do. However, I just found out that there is a plugin Maven2Bazel - so I will try to start a new plugin project with Maven, and convert it to bazel. maybe I will find new insights there.